# Ng-Bootstrap gives me Error "An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context" when launching Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

As mentioned above I tried to add ng-bootstrap to my Angular 9 Project. I added it to my AppModule and tried to add it to a Submodule as well. Both methods resulting in this error:

```
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.d.ts:101:9 - error TS1086: An accessor 
cannot be declared in an ambient context.

get ngbTooltip(): string | TemplateRef<any>;
```

A google search revealed that it could habe to do with not proper updated angular cli, so I updated any package to recent version and the cli too, but the error is still the same. I even added plain `bootstrap.css` to my project, but nothing changes.

So I hope anyone faced this error too or know how to fix this.

```
"dependencies": {
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^1.9.7",
    "all": "^0.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1"
}
```

The Entry Point:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterNewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgbModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [Title]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The RegisterNewComponent HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>  
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>   
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>   
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: What is the version of ngbootstrap and angular?

Comment: Can you post the component and app.module ?

Comment: you should use this version for Angular 9 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.2" and run npm install again

Comment: Sure I added it